# how to compare type of an object's instance to a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

how can i write this code in java?

```
public class ComponentsManager 
    {
        private List<IComponent> list = new ArrayList<IComponent>();

        public <U extends IComponent> U GetComponent() {

            for (IComponent component : list) {

                if(component instanceof U)
                {
                    return component;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

but i cant perform instanceof on generic types. how should i do it?
thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Basically you can't do that due to type erasure.  The normal workaround is to pass a `Class` object as a parameter; e.g.

```
    public <U extends IComponent> U GetComponent(Class<U> clazz) {
        for (IComponent component : list) {
            if (clazz.isInstance(component)) {
                return clazz.cast(component);
            }
        }
    }
```

You could also use `if (clazz.equals(component.getClass())) { ...` but that does an exact type match ... which is not what the `instanceof` operator does.  The `instanceof` operator and the `Class.instanceOf` method both test to see if the value's type is *assignment compatible*.

Comment: @Steven C: Would you care to comment on my answer? Everyone says 'can't' yet my little demo works..

Comment: Why wouldn't Oracle/Java add the possibility for a generic type to access the .class field(/method/identifier)? Am I right to assume that the reason relates to what happens compile time vs runtime?

Comment: The fundamental reason for this is type erasure.  The fundamental reason for type erasure is that generic types needed to be implemented as a compile time mechanism (in Java 5) for compatibility with earlier versions of Java.

Comment: The name "clazz" of the parameter kind of weirds me out. But it seems that almost every example of this on SO uses the exact same name.

Comment: Try using `class` instead and see what happens.   (Then turn down your "weirdness sensor".)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't. You'll have to take a `Class` object as a parameter:

```
public <U extends IComponent> U getComponent(Class<U> clazz) {
    // ...
    if (component.getClass() == clazz) {
        return (U) component;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
getComponent(MyComponentImpl.class);
```

Comment: You're right @Stephen. I forgot to cast the result. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: that won't compile either.  Try it and see.

Comment: @Stephen: I tried it and it works (at least in Eclipse using JDK 6). It compiles with an "Unchecked cast" warning, but it works fine. What error do you get?

Comment: that's what I mean.  Most people consider those to be anathema.  The problem is that while it is safe in practice, a small change will result in it being unsafe.  For this reason, it is a bad idea to ignore or suppress it.  Instead you should treat it as a hard compilation error and fix it.

Answer (score 2):

General rule with java - if a generic class needs to know its generic type(s), then you have to pass a hint. A common approach for the problem is using the constructor:

```
public class ComponentsManager<U extends IComponent> {
  private Class<U extends IComponentManeger> genericType = null;
  public ComponentsManager<U extends IComponent>(
                       Class<U extends IComponent> genericType) {
    this.genericType = genericType;
  }

}
```

Now the class knows it's generic type class and you can uses the generic type class instance to verify, if a component in your collection matches the classes generic type.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a couple of 'test' methods:

```
private static <U extends IComponent> boolean testComponent(U u) {
  return true;
}

private static boolean testComponent(Object o) {
  return false;
}
```

Then, use `testComponent(component)` instead of `component instanceof U`.

**Example code:**

```
import java.util.*;

class IComponent {
}

class T1 extends IComponent {
}

public class Test {

  public static <U extends IComponent> boolean testComponent(U u) {
    return true;
  }

  public static boolean testComponent(Object o) {
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    T1 t = new T1();
    System.out.println("hm? " + (testComponent(t) ? "true" : "false"));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

hm? true

Comment: (Since @sje397 asked me to comment ...): This will "work", but you have to do an unsafe type conversion inside the `GetComponent` method ... or change it to a non-generic method.  In addition, you are duplicating Java's type checking by adding your own ersatz type checking.  This is cumbersome, and the end solution is more fragile than a solution that uses real Java type checking.

Comment: Even given Stephen's comments, this is useful. Oh wait, this does not seem to compile "identical type erasure". @sje397: is this working for you? Apparently you have to include the methods within EACH class? that is not so useful then ..

Comment: All this "answer" does is demonstrate that you can direct objects that extend IComponent to a particular method. The problem is that once you are in that method, type erasure means you don't know that it is a "U", so you can't do any reasoning based on "U" -- which is what is needed to address the question. All that is known inside the method "testComponent", is that "u" is an IComponent. A better test would have been to pass *two* parameters, "U u" and  "IComponent other", then show that you could determine whether "other" is a "U". But at that point, is better to pass in the desired class.

Comment: Or to put it another way:  ***of course*** it returns true That's merely a demonstration of overloading; a non-generic method with parameter IComponent would have the exact same behaviour. Now prove that the "u extends IComponent" gains you anything. I don't think it does, but even if I am wrong, passing in a Class would be a cleaner way to accomplish the result.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly generic type can't be treated as a normal variable in code, which makes it hard to do comparing directly. However the reflective class, `ParameterizedType`, could help you get an instance representing a parameterized type, which is basically practicable objects.

```
Type genericSuperType = object.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
Type[] actualTypeParams = ((ParameterizedType) genericSuperType).getActualTypeArguments()
if (actualTypeParams[0] instanceof Class) {
    ((Class) actualTypeParams[0]).isInstance(testingObj);
}
```

For more details about the usage upon `ParameterizedType` and corresponding `TypeVariable`, the internal util class, [TypeParameterMatcher`, in Netty](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/446b38db5220a3934064ee4e26f40d81dfa6b714/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/internal/TypeParameterMatcher.java) could be referenced.